# Distinguish between null and blank values within dataframe columns (pyspark)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to know if there exist any method or something which can help me to distinguish between real null values and blank values.
As far as I know dataframe is treating blank values like null.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there is

```
Df.filter((df.4.isNull()) | (df.4 == "")).show()
```

This should work

Comment: Single quotes these are , they appear a lil weird

Comment: Sorry for the huge delay with the reaction. This is the solution which I used. Anyway I had to use double quotes, otherwise there was an error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: make sure to include both filters in their own brackets, I received data type mismatch when one of the filter was not it brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Spark dataframe column has isNull method.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (0, 1, 2, 5, None),
    (1, 1, 2, 3, ''), # this is blank
    (2, 1, 2, None, None) # this is null
], ["id", '1', '2', '3', '4'])
```

As you see below second row with blank values at '4' column is filtered:

```
df.filter(df['4'].isNull()).show()
+---+---+---+----+----+
| id|  1|  2|   3|   4|
+---+---+---+----+----+
|  0|  1|  2|   5|null|
|  2|  1|  2|null|null|
+---+---+---+----+----+
```